# The King's Sob Story

Tags: story, cipher

It's late at night, and something very peculiar is happening. From your room, you can hear cries of true misery! Someone is wailing and repeating "O' woe is me!" over, and over again, and it's starting to get quite annoying, so naturally you decide to follow the sounds, and, lo and behold, you find the King of Acting himself, sobbing outside the drama studio!

"What's wrong, your highness?", you ask, to which he responds by reciting a very strange and contemporary monologue of sorts, throwing the script at you:

> Oh woe is me,
>   Two terms combined,
>   Those yews are ours,
>   Beginning and end, intertwined.
>   
>   Begging for amnesty,
>   They flow,
>   In a sea of decay,
>   But Never giving up Hope,
>   In what remains.

...Aaaaand he's gone back to his wailing. You look at the script he's handed you. It looks like any normal script, except at the bottom of the page, scrawled in messy handwriting:

> DUVCOPLOZUM

How incredibly strange... Perhaps you can try and figure out what has upset the King so much?

Comment: Not sure of how to use it, but it seems that some of the poem is hinting at letters to be used >!"O" woe is me... Those "U"s are "R"s... a "C" of "D" "K"

Comment: (I don't think you can put spoiler blocks in comments.) I suspect "O woe" is actually "O O". I guess the "U"s in the scrawl need to be turned into "R"s. I wonder whether the C of DK is coincidence. Note also: "amnesty" ends with ST.

Comment: I think Z is an A (Beginning and End intertwined)

Comment: You're all definitely on the right track!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> BROKENHEART
>
>  This is created by substituting the letters in DUVCOPLOZUM

### Explanations:

Oh woe is me, Two terms combined,

> O O = E  (@Gareth McCaughan)

Those yews are ours

> U = R (@elmer007)

Beginning and end, intertwined.

> Z = A (@gannolloy)

Begging for Amnesty

> M = T (Amnesty = M is T)

They flow,

> ??? V = O

In a sea of decay,

> C = K

---

At this point, we have

> _ROKE__EART

---

But Never giving up Hope,
In what remains.

> Fill in the blanks with B, N, and H. (@feelinferrety)
>
>   BROKENHEART

Comment: B... N... H... in what remains.

Comment: Yup, that's right! They flow is just the sound 'They' = V, 'flow' = O

Comment: I'm still at a loss for how 'They' sounds like 'V'. 'We' sounds like 'V' to me, though.

Comment: @shieldbug1: Neither of those sounds like the corresponding letter. The "Th" and "V" sounds are different in English, and "ey" is not the vowel "ee" in V.

Comment: The main consonant sound in "they" sounds quite similar to the V consonant sound to me, at least, sorry!

Comment: @Deusovi Wait, shieldbug's profile says hes from Australia. So with an Australian accent, V could be pronounced 'Vay' instead of 'Vee'

Comment: @WesleySitu It's not the letter name of V, but rather the sound of V that I was trying to hint

Comment: The sounds are phonetically quite similar, and [can merge in some dialects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th-fronting). However, they are different for most speakers. Personally, I would not have gotten that "they" was meant to clue the letter V.